# Populating ListView with DataGrid ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml

I found an example of a ListView with the following code:

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
        <Grid>
            <DataGrid Margin="15"
                      Height="500"
                      Width="1280"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding ChildDetails}"
                      Style="{DynamicResource MainDataGridStyle}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"
                                        Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age"
                                        Binding="{Binding Surname}" />

                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mail"
                                        Binding="{Binding Mail}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

---

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ParentDetails}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate1}"
               x:Name="person_listView" Margin="0,0,10,138"  SelectionMode="Multiple">        
    </ListView>
```

---

ChildDetails and ParentDetails are aparently `ObservableCollection<Parent>` and `ObservableCollection<Child>`.

What I don't understand is why are there 2 types of objects? The ListView is displaying only ChildDetails. 
How can I bind a single list of objects to the DataGrid?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Apparently ChildDetails is a (collection-type) property of the element type of the ParentDetails collection. ParentDetails itself is a collection-type property of the main view model.

Comment: But how can I use only one collection for the DataGrid? I know it's a stupid question, I'm still learning wpf, sorry

Comment: There is only one collection - ChildDetails - used as the ItemsSource of the DataGrid. The fact that the DataGrid in your example is part of a DataTemplate is irrelevant. You can use it anywhere you want.

Comment: I still don't get it why there is ParentDetails in ListView as source and ChildDetails in DataGrid. If it helps here is the code behind: https://codeshare.io/5zyeBb

Comment: Why do you need a DataGrid? If you are trying to populate a ListView with data you simply need to set its ItemsSource to an IEnumerable<T> and define its GridViewColumns in the XAML markup. There is a basic and complete code sample here that I believe can't be misunderstood: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-with-gridview/.

Comment: I needed a ListView with custom columnheaders and margins; this was the only one that worked. As far as I was told ListView control cannot be styled itself, thats why DataGrid was added.
Thanks for the link, will check it out!